# Remote Google Cloud SQL connection from Cpanel

Tags: php, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL from an external host (NOT Google App Engine).
I added my server's IP address as an Authorized network, however I keep getting the following error:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

I am able to connect from my computer using MySQL workbench, however the connection is refused from the server where I'm hosting my app. I am connecting using PHP as follows:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("173.x.x.x", "root", "xxx", "instance-name:database-name");
```

Do you know what could be the problem, especially that the network is already authorized in Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: You are using workbench on your local computer and your app is hosted on a different computer in a different location with a different ip. Is that right? If so, you should whitelist both ips.

Comment: Hello, yep I've already whitelisted both IPs. With workbench locally it works well, however from the server it's still blocked for some reason :(

Comment: What host are you using and do they allow remote db access? And is your remote db on 3306 port or a different one?

Comment: Im managing my app host through Cpanel, my remote db (the google Cloud SQL) is on 3306

Comment: Apparently this is not permitted from the side of my app's host, thanks for the hint, i'll check how to solve it...